# DJI Virtual Stick Controls are not properly applied

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I am building a drone application that will send flight commands for indoor flight. I am implementing DJI Mobile SDK's Virtual Sticks that are described [here](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/component-guide-flightController.html#virtual-sticks).

After experimenting with DJI's Simulator Tutorial found [here](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/SimulatorDemo.html#implementing-virtualstickview), I implemented a trimmed-down, non-simulation version for my application. When I tested my application outdoors, the controls work consistently and correctly.

However, when I go indoors, the drone only performs 1 action regardless of the command sent: the drone flies in the direction of its back-left propeller. The drone will always fly in this direction even if the command is only to turn the drone.

Any ideas what could be happening? I'm not sure what code to post since my code works outdoors.

**UPDATE #1**

Here are my flight controller settings (implemented in Swift):

```
self.flightController = (DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft)?.flightController

self.flightController?.rollPitchControlMode = DJIVirtualStickRollPitchControlMode.velocity
self.flightController?.yawControlMode = DJIVirtualStickYawControlMode.angle
self.flightController?.rollPitchCoordinateSystem = DJIVirtualStickFlightCoordinateSystem.body
```

**UPDATE #2**

Code to change Yaw (with some hardcoded numbers). Basically is used to make the drone turn completely around.

```
private var turnTime = 0
private var turnTimer: Timer? = nil

func turn() {
    self.turnTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: (#selector(turnDroneCommand)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func turnDroneCommand() {
    self.turnTime += 1

    let data = DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData(pitch: 0, roll: 0, yaw: Float(180), verticalThrottle: 0)

    self.flightController.send(data, withCompletion: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Fire custom error callback
        }
    })

    if self.turnTime >= 7 {
        self.turnTimer?.invalidate()
        self.turnTime = 0
        // Fire custom success callback
    }
}
```

I've implemented an almost identical method for changing the pitch. As stated perviously, the current outcome is no different for either command.

Comment: Could you please tell what your [rollPitchCoordinateSystem](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=rollpitchcoordinatesystem&i=0&#djiflightcontroller_rollpitchcoordinatesystem_inline) is before you  send virtual stick data? I suspect that you are trying to use the ground coordinate system `DJIVirtualStickFlightCoordinateSystemGround` and you have no GPS indoors, so it is behaving weirdly.

Comment: @aksh1t Unfortunately, I have set the rollPitchCoordinateSystem to `DJIVirtualStickFlightCoordinateSystemBody`. That knowledge about `DJIVirtualStickFlightCoordinateSystemGround` is still nice to know though.

Comment: Interesting. Your flight controller settings look okay to me. If possible, could you post a sample of the DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData struct that you are sending, and what you expect the drone to do? (Better still would be a github link to your project). Also, what drone was this?

Comment: @aksh1t Sample posted. I'll see what I can do about a github link. The drone is a Matrice 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long back-and-forth with the devs at DJI, I can now offer a partial solution.

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**

If you look at the code provided in Update #2 of the question, you'll notice the following lines:

```
self.turnTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: (#selector(turnDroneCommand)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and

```
self.turnTime += 1
...
if self.turnTime >= 7 {
    self.turnTimer?.invalidate()
    self.turnTime = 0
    // Fire custom success callback
}
```

The timeInterval parameter is set to 0.2 seconds. This means the commands are being sent at a frequency of 5Hz for less then 2 seconds. According to the developers at DJI, commands need to be sent at a frequency of 10Hz (or greater, but I have not verified this) for **longer** then 2 seconds.

**OUTSTANDING ISSUE**

The Matrice 100 (M100) still "drifts" towards the back left propeller before executing the virtual stick commands. The devs at DJI do not appear to have access to a M100 and cannot test it themselves. Since it appears (based on very, very limited testing) to be a problem unique to the M100, it may not be a problem with the Mobile SDK itself.

I am marking this as the answer in case someone stumbles on the "ignore command" problem with another DJI drone. If a solution for the drifting is found, I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with  virtual RC on the M100, it's a problem with the M100 firmware not the sdk. we are not using any SDK, we use direct serial commands direct to the the com port onboard  the M100. We abandoned trying to use virtual RC and now send velocity commands which work perfectly.